# How much torque is required to lift 27 kg at 1 m distance to go 90° in 8 seconds?

Tags: torque

strong text[image]

I know 27 kg × 9.8 ms<sup>-2</sup> = 264.6 N
Torque = 264.6 × 1 m = 264.6 Nm
but how much required to go 90° in 8 seconds?

Comment: Just for the lovely penmanship... I'm assuming they're talking about fixed torque the whole way, hope this is correct but can't be sure. If so, it wouldn't move much at first, then would speed up considerably torward the end. Also if constant torque, it wouldn't be at rest at the end, hopefully that's what is intended... first equation: write out angular acceleration, as function of angle and fixed torque - note the force exerted by gravity points down and thus torque depend on angle; second equation: kinematics, angle vs variable angular acceleration, set it to arrive in 8 seconds. then solve

Comment: also, hopefully we're looking at a side view, not top-down

Comment: If you applied 264.6 Nm it will just sit there in equilibrium. So, draw a similar diagram at an angle of theta to the horizontal, work out the FBD, and you'll get a simple (I hope) equation involving integration.

Comment: Why did you multiply 27 kg with `g`? Can you draw an arrow showing the "*down*" direction in which gravity acts? If the diagram shows an arm and a mass laying down on a horizontal tabletop, then `g` is probably not supposed to appear in the calculations at all. If `g` did appear, you are basically asking for the solution of a non linear differential equation. Please clarify the above points using the [edit] option below your question.

Comment: Because its a side view. Gravity pulling that 27kg down.

Comment: @GregLocock sorry can you explain little more.

Comment: Define the acceleration at an angle theta for a given torque, and then integrate that from 0 to pi/2. I think this is actually quite a tricky problem to solve, but at the very least you need to be able to write the differential equation.

Comment: I think a numerical approach is more likely to work than trying to solve the differential equation because the mixture of thetadotdot and sin(theta) is tricky. The last sentence is odd, does that mean it starts at t=2 and gets to 9 at t=10?

Comment: I think the differential equation you need to solve is m*g*r*sin(theta)+m*r^2*thetadotdot-T=0

Answer (score 0):

You shall think in terms of the Energy required for the rotational body:

$E_{\tau} = \dfrac{1}{2}I\omega^2$

I think you know all the terms, just watch out for the units of each.

Comment: No, you've ignored the gravitational potential energy